# python setup.py install in anaconda without sudo

Tags: python, anaconda, setup.py

I have a local package XYZ that I usually (sucessfully) install using:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Now instead of a systemwide python installation, I installed Anaconda (for OSX) in my home directory under `~/anaconda3`. Running the above command without `sudo`, I expected the package to be automatically installed in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

but instead the command results in:

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'XYZ.egg-info/PKG-INFO'
```

so apparently `setup.py install` tries to write somewhere where only root has access to. Appreciate any hint on this...

### UPDATE:

I tried with `sudo`. Actually by using `sudo` the files do get installed in the local path. Only the owner is root. So I had to `chwon` the files to myself manually. It would be nice to find out why `sudo` is needed by `setup.py` at all for installing in my own home folder?

Comment: are you using the system or the anaconda python? ``which python`` should tell you.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano definitely anaconda's python.

Comment: This is most likely because this directory is created by the install process with sudo, and is owned by the root user. Try `sudo rm -r XYZ.egg-info` and install with anaconda python again

Comment: wow @darthbith, that was it! it is because I had run the command before using sudo, the egg belonged to root. silly me.... If you write this as an answer I will mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because when you first ran `sudo setup.py install`, the `XYZ.egg_info` directory was created (in the same folder as the setup.py file) and was set to be owned by the root user. To remove this folder (and any other debris from previous installs) you can run

```
sudo python setup.py clean --all
```

or by manually removing them using, e.g., `sudo rm -r XYZ.egg_info`